# Setting up dual monitors on a AMD Radeon HD 6800 series

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have two VGA monitors, and two DVI to VGA adaptors. My GPU (AMD Radeon HD 6800 series) has no VGA slots, just 2 DVI slots and one HDMI slot. When I connect the monitors, only one of them works. The other one just displays "Check signal cable".

I have tried connecting the other adaptor to the slot, it still doesn't work (but the adaptor itself works on the primary slot) and I've tried changing the monitors (both monitors work fine when connected to the primary slot.

Both the slots are DVI-I dual link.

Comment: It looks like you don't have to DVI slots, but one DVI-I slot and one DVI-D: http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=45381 If that forum is correct, you'd need to get an HDMI -> VGA converter. Which video card do you specifically have?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to find out.

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/telepresence/endpoint/articles/cisco_telepresence_movi_find_out_graphics_card_driver_on_windows_pc_kb_540.html

Comment: How do I find out which graphics card and driver my Windows pc has?

If you are not sure which card is in the computer, the exact name of your graphics card is available in the Windows Display Settings, that you can find through the Control Panel. You can also run Microsoft's DirectX diagnostic tool to get this information:

From the Start menu, open the Run dialog box.
Type dxdiag
Click on the Display tab of the dialog that opens to find graphics card information.
This article applies to the following products:

Cisco Jabber Video for TelePresence

Comment: It just says AMD Radeon HD 6800 series everywhere.

Comment: Did your video card come with drivers? Or did you just put it in the machine and let the OS take care of it? What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. I installed the drivers manually with a disk that came with the card.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking it might be a driver issue. But if you installed it from the original location thats probably not it. Does the disk have the model number on it anywhere?  Would be useful to know because it looks like the two 6800 series cards have different output types; wouldn't want to giv eyou the wrong info

Comment: Just driver version 13-022 and Sapphire.

Comment: hm thats interesting.  It looks like both models have an HDMI. If I were in your shoes I'd try an HDMI converter instead of the two DVI converters but unfortunately I don't know if that'll be guaranteed to work for you.